# Angular Show/Hide <object> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, swfobject

I have a list of files of different formats. What I want to achieve is a gallery with *preview* functionality. Everything works great if you click through items of the same format (e.g jpg)
but when I click on a SWF file it creates correctly the `<object>` element and I get the preview but, if after previewing an SWF I click on a JPEG file, it shows me previews for both elements, `<object>` and `<img>`.

How can I Show/Hide `<object>` elements?

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
<ng-object ng-if="file.format == 'swf'"
    width="{{file.width}}"
    height="{{file.height}}"
    ng-data="{{file.url}}">
</ng-object>

<img ng-if="file.format != 'swf'" ng-src="{{file.url}}" />
```

Comment: if that's not working, try wrapping your object in a div and move the ng-if directive to that div.

Comment: My thought is that ng-if declares whether the element is rendered on the page or not based on the condition you specified. Once it's rendered, it will be always visible (or not if you specified display: none). So in your case it'd be better to use ng-show instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yauheni Leichanok Thanks for your comment. It worked great for me.

ng-show was the correct answer.